# Is there a more elementary way to arrive at: $\ln(m)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{mn}\frac{1}{k}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms, digamma-function

Let $\psi$ denote the digamma function, and let $m,n\in\Bbb N_1$. For $m=1$, use the empty sum as $\ln(1)=0$ anyway!

The Gauss multiplication tells us that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\psi\left(n+\frac{i}{m}\right)=-m\ln m+\psi(mn+1)-\psi(n+1)$$

Recalling the harmonic relations of digamma, and allowing for loose limit notation, this becomes:

$$\begin{align}m\left(-\ln m+\sum_{k=1}^{mn}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{mk}\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{m-1}{k}-\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\frac{m}{mk+mn-i}\right)\\-m\ln m+\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\frac{m}{mk-i}&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{m-1}{k}-\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\frac{m}{mk-i}\\-m\ln m&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{m-1}{k}-m\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{mk-i}\right) \end{align}$$

Introducing explicit limits, one finds:

$$\begin{align}-m\ln m&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N\left(\frac{m-1}{k}-m\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{mk-i}\right)\\&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{m-1}{k}-m\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m\cdot N}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{mk}\right)\\&=\lim_{N\to\infty}-\sum_{k=N+1}^{m\cdot N}\frac{m}{k}\end{align}$$

That is:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{mn}\frac{1}{k}=\ln m$$

For all $m\in\Bbb N_1$. Amusingly, Desmos corroborates it for fractional $m$, but how exactly a fractional sum is computed there I am unsure!

I discovered this by accident whilst fiddling around with some other digamma calculations.

Is it in fact well known? If so, what are the more elementary ways of deriving it? I assume that if this is well known then more elementary ways exist.

Comment: You can use the fact that $(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}) -\log n$ is convergent (converges to the Euler-Macheroni constant). There are several proofs for this fact.

Comment: For the case $m=1$, what does it mean to sum from $n+1$ to $n$?

Comment: @BarryCipra I suppose for all $m\in\Bbb N_2$ would have been better then! Since $\ln(1)=0$, one could perhaps employ the convention of the empty sum

Comment: @FShrike, I'm inclined toward the empty sum. That would agree with Circle Lover's displayed equation (though they should then change their $\lt$'s to $\le$'s to include the case $m=1$).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{mn}\frac{1}{k}$$ is a Riemann Sum of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ in the interval $[1,m]$, so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{mn}\frac{1}{k} = \int_1^m\frac{1}{x}dx = \log(m)$$

Comment: It is not immediately clear to me how you’re partitioning there

Comment: Take $x_k = 1+\frac{k}{n}$ with $k = 0, 1, \ldots , (m-1)n$

Comment: It may help to visualize this, if you first substitute $k=n+l$ where $l=1..(m-1)n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$S:=\sum_{k=n+1}^{nm}\frac1k=\int_n^{nm}\frac{dt}{\lceil t\rceil}$$ so that

$$\int_n^{nm}\dfrac{dt}{t+1}< S< \int_n^{nm}\dfrac{dt}{t}.$$

The exact bounds are $\log\left(\dfrac{nm+1}{n+1}\right)$ and $\log(m)$.

Comment: See my comment(s) below the OP regarding the case $m=1$.

Answer (score -1):

If $n\gg 1$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{mn} 1/k \sim \ln mn+\gamma$,
$\sum_{k=1}^{n}1/k\sim \ln n+\gamma$. Hence $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{mn} 1/k\sim \ln mn-\ln n =\ln m.$$ This can be easily converted to a $(\epsilon, N)$-proof. Take $n>N$ big enough so that $|Sum_1-\ln mn-\gamma|\lt \epsilon$, and $|Sum_2-\ln n-\gamma|\lt \epsilon$, hence $-\epsilon< Sum_1-\ln mn-\gamma <\epsilon$, $-\epsilon< Sum_2-\ln n-\gamma <\epsilon$,  and subtract.

Comment: Asymptotic equivalences can't in general be added. One needs to keep track of the error.

Comment: @jjagmath In this case, we know that the *absolute* error tends to $0$.

Comment: You do not need to deal with those epsilons, just say that $
\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^j {1/k}  = \log j + \gamma  + o(1)
$ as $j\to +\infty$.

Comment: But then you have to subtract $\gamma$.

Comment: That you did not subtract it. For example, it should be $|Sum_1 -\ln mn -\gamma|<\epsilon$.